# CakePHP 1.3 and TCPDF: how to return to controller after printing PDF

Tags: cakephp, tcpdf

I'm using CakePHP 1.3 and TCPDF to print a PDF file using `print_pdf.ctp`. I'm having trouble redirecting the page to the referrer after this print. The commented section of the controller action is not reached.. How do I manage this?

Note that `print_pdf()` is linked to a button. So, the user loads a page, presses the "Print" button linked to `print_pdf` action, and a PDF file is printed when this button is clicked. The reason I'd like to redirect is that the `print_pdf` action updates some data and the page where the button is located needs to be refreshed to reflect this update.

Controller:

```
// This action is linked to a button
function print_pdf() {
    ...    
    $this->layout = 'pdf'; //this will use the pdf.ctp layout
    $this->render();   

    // Line below are not executed
    ...
    $this->redirect($this->referer());
}
```

Comment: Once you hit render, it's going to load up the page.  Can you make those changes before going to the PDF?  Alternatively could you open a new tab/window, make the changes, then close that tab?

Comment: If I redirect the page before the render, it will not print the PDF. I've also tried Javascript where I assign a page refresh to the `print_pdf` button, but this also doesn't work because the page is just refreshed before the `print_pdf` action can be executed. Do I have to redirect in the `print_pdf` View or something? (this doesn't seem proper)

Comment: You may have to do this via an AJAX call using JavaScript ; click the button; send an Ajax call to the server and update the database, when the Ajax call returns 'success', update the information and open the PDF

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do.  You are trying to redirect to another page to save some information, and then immediately display a PDF to the person?

Why not just run whatever save your doing from inside the PDF function:

```
// This action is linked to a button
function print_pdf() {
    ...
    //$this->redirect($this->referer());
    //Put whatever you were going to redirect to before the render.  Instead of  redirecting just run the thing as part of this function.
    ...    
    $this->layout = 'pdf'; //this will use the pdf.ctp layout
    // Line below are not executed
    $this->render();     
}
```

$this->render();  should escape the controller and go straight to the view.  You can't put anything after it.  If you want to make changes to the page with the button, you can do that before the render.

Comment: I'm basically redirecting to the same page to refresh the page to reflect that the PDF has been printed. If I redirect before rendering, the PDF download prompt does not appear. I'd like the user to be able to get the "download" window so that he can download the PDF file.